# Get 100% of image background showing on website, no matter the screen size

Tags: html, image, css

I'm sure I poorly structered that question title, but this is what I'm trying to do:
*Key: image = moving picture behind submit form*

Problem 1: Get the background image to stay at that perfect size no matter the width of the page.
  Get the entire frame of the moving image showing.
 When the image is at the perfect width (http://gyazo.com/702e443a6b814b1abc26a801836f4d6f) it shows the entire image.
 When the width is increased even more, the image starts to 'zoom in'. (Which I don't want.)

Problem 2: On mobile devices with much smaller screens, most of the image is cut off (and you can't scroll to see the rest).
  Get the entire frame of the moving image showing.
 Have the entire image centered and the user should be able to see the entire frame of the image.

This is what my code looks like for the image:

```
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/a4/79/4c/a4794cbfe048505d9645339738a8ddc7.jpg");
    height: 60%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2x3xdw2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
#top{
    background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/a4/79/4c/a4794cbfe048505d9645339738a8ddc7.jpg");
    height: 60%;
    background-position: center -150px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Because you were using the `background-size: 100%;` you're telling the browser to scale the image for you. By removing it and positioning the background you'll achieve what you want with the image never resizing.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nx8nbxpw/)

**Note:** You'll need to make sure that your image is large enough that when the page is stretched really large that you won't see the background. It will be hard to do, given that screen resolutions are getting so large now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#your_image_container_id {
     width: 100%;
}
```

What you are trying to say is called "Responsive Web Design". In order to achieve RWD, you never use absolute units such as pixels, points... but rather use relative units such as `%`, `em` which scales according to size of the screen. but you have do some calculation though such as `%`, make sure all elements on same row do not have the total of with percentage of over 100%, or something like that and also have to compensate for paddings and margins.